# Excel - Create derived column using values from two different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a weird Excel question. I have two columns, lets call them "Claim" and "Outcome". The "Claim" value can be repeated multiple times with different values in the "Outcome" column. Sample example below

| Claim | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Pay |
| 1234 | Deny |
| 1234 | Pay |
| 2345 | Pay |
| 2345 | Pay |
| 2345 | Pay |

I now want to add a third derived column called "Overall Outcome", which says if all "Outcome" for a specific value in the "Claim" column is Pay then "Overall Outcome is "Pay" else "Deny". How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, you want a third column to say "Pay" if any record for the claim says "Pay"? If yes, you can use COUNTIFS to count if "Pay" exists (>0) for each claim number.

The formula for column 3, row 2 would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(OutcomeRange,"Pay",ClaimRange,A2)>0,"Pay","Deny")

=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,"Pay",A:A,A2)>0,"Pay","Deny")
```

EDIT: Based on the additional parameters in the comments where you have three possible outcomes (and possibly more if you want to extend this in future), I would create a table to hold my outcome possibilities. I will use VLOOKUP so keep this table in alphabetical order.

| Outcome | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Deny | 0 |
| Partial Deny | 0 |
| Pay | 2 |
| Pending | 1 |

In column C, use VLOOKUP (I've named my table Tbl_Status, this could be on another sheet) to find the outcome value for each row in your data:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Tbl_Status,2,FALSE)
```

Then in column D you can use mathematical comparisons to evaluate the final outcome.

```
=IF(MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,A2)=0,"Deny",IF(AND(MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,A2)=2,MINIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,A2)=2),"Pay","Partial Pay"))
```

The first MAXIFS will return "Deny" if all entries are Deny or Partial Deny (they both have value 0 in the lookup table), otherwise the IF statement will then check whether than maximum and minimum are both 2 (i.e. all Pay), if it fails it will return 'Partial.'

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this works. Had a follow-up question, what if there were multiple values in column B, like Pay, Deny, Pend for Pay - would I use an OR statement. Essentially if a claim has all pay, then Pay, all deny, then deny, and if neither then Pend for Pay.

Comment: Thanks, Mayukh. I edited my posted.

Kyle - I changed it to the following, it works but want to confirm

=if(COUNTIFS(C:C,"D",A:A,A57)>0,"Deny",if(countifs(C:C,"P",A:A,A57)>0,"Partial Pay","Pay"))

Comment: @Ankit, your modification will show Deny for any claim number which has a Deny line, because it will satisfy the first IF statement. Are you perhaps looking for a formula which returns 'Deny' if ALL lines are deny, return 'Partial' if there is at least one Pay and Deny, and Pay if ALL lines are pay?

Comment: Yes, Kyle what you mentioned is exactly correct. That is the exactly what I am looking. The situation gets complicated because my column B can have other values like Partial Deny (same as Deny) and Pend. So I need a formula that:

- If all lines are Pay, then overall status is Pay
- if all lines are deny or partial deny, then overall status is Pay
- if lines are a mix of Pay, Pend, Deny/Partial Deny, then overall status is Partial Pay.

Comment: I've edited the answer with one possible way of doing this. You could do this without the VLOOKUP and separate table but this is somewhat more manageable.

Answer (score 4):

Go at it the other way: If one or more outcomes for a given claim is "Deny", then output is "Deny", else, output is "Pay":

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"Deny")>0,"Deny","Pay")
```